# Como identificar o elemento HTML em que um script js está contido?

Tags: javascript

Assim: Eu coloco um script js dentro de uma div, por exemplo. Como eu posso fazer esse script identificar a DIV em que está contido sem seletores como ID ou Class?

É que vejo alguns scripts de incorporação que inserem coisas (imagens, videos e etc) dentro do elemento em que eles são colocados, sem precisar usar seletores. Como isso é feito?

OBS: Javascript puro. Estou aprendendo o js puro.

Obrigado e boa tarde à todos.

Comment: Mas  a div tem uma identificação ?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do código que referes para percebermos melhor a que te referes? _"vejo alguns scripts de incorporação que inserem coisas [...] dentro do elemento em que eles são colocados"_

Answer (score 1):

Se você não quer recuperar pelo Id ou Class. Você pode recuperar pela TagName.

```
document.getElementsByTagName
```

No exemplo abaixo, criei uma `<Li>` de bebidas e também criei uma `<span>` para adicionar o valor recuperado via javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Bebidas</p>
<ul>
  <li>Coca Cola</li>
  <li>Pepsi</li>
  <li>Fanta</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="minhaFuncao()">Clique Aqui</button>

<span></span>

<script>
function minhaFuncao() {
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    var span = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    span.innerHTML = li[1].innerHTML;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Você consegue passar o elemento por parâmetro usando o comando `this`.

Exemplo:

```
function teste(elemento) { ... }
```

em seguida:

```
<div onclick="teste(this);"></div>
```